# Select n items from a set of subsets

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

I'm wondering if there exists an algorithm that can solve this problem:

Suppose you have a set with sets in it where each set may or may not have elements, for example, let the possible elements of the sets be 1,2, and 3, then we would have for example a set like {{1,2,3}{1}{1,2} ... } so, how do I select a number of sets such that I have **n** elements of each item, for example, let n=200 then I want 200 **1s**, 200 **2s** and 200 **3s** in this example.

Comment: Do you want _exactly_ n elements of each item? This is not guaranteed to be possible. For instance in your example how would you get a solution for n=2?

Comment: SyntaxError in your code ... also those may be lists, but not a set. the inner things are lists ... but a set can not contain lists as they are mutable. [mre] and plenty of clarification needed.

Comment: Don't use tags as wishlist - use tags that pertain to your shown code. Your code is not even python to start with.

Comment: Yes, It's not python, It's an algorithm question, I added the python tag only to let you know that I would like as a response python related code.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I think its pretty evident that the codeblock is psuedocode for the conceptual data format. I think they're also referring to "set" in a mathematical sense, rather than Python's **set**.  However, they should indeed clarify, or instead provide valid Python examples (since they're requesting a Python answer).

Comment: @gimix, yes I know that it's not always possible.

Comment: Seems related to the Set Cover problem, and maybe also to the 0-1 Bin-Packing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before I dive into an answer there are some interrogatives.

suppose we have a method f() that given a set of sets (as the one in your example), what does it need to find?

If we plug n = 3 to f(3) it needs to find the sets such that we have n elements of each item ( 3 1s, 3 2s, and 3 3s) exactly? Let's suppose this scenario.

Then the output of our method should be the subsets of the sets that satisfy the previous problem or do we only need to return the number of sets in our subsets?
for example f(3) in a set of sets as follows

```
[[1,2,3][1][1,2][1,2][1,2,3][3]... ]
```

we can see that a solution subset is `[[1,2,3][1,2][1,2,3][3]]`
We can return this subset or rather the number of sets in this subset which is 4. (This could be relevant for the space complexity of the algorithm).

Now to the solution, a Naive approach could be of this form:

1. loop through the set of sets.
2. for each element in the individual set, increase an element counter (for example the set [1,2] will increase the 1 and 2 counter by one each.

   1. if one of the element count is greater than 'n', then we do not consider that set into our solution.
   2. else, consider the set into your solution set.
   3. Whatever the case, call your method again but don't consider the previous set.
   4. return if you find that each element has increased the counter equal to 'n'.

a pseudo code will look something like this:

```
method find_sets(n,sets, sol_sets, element_counters):

    for each set in sets:
        updated_counter = element_counter +  1 for each element in set
        sets = sets.pop(set)

        if for a element in updated_counter > n:
            return method find_sets(n, sets, sol_sets, element_counters)

        else if for any element in updated_counter < n:
            sol_sets.add(set)
            return method find_sets(n, sets, sol_sets, updated_counter)

        else if for every element in updated_counter = n:
            sol_sets.add(set)
            return sol_sets

    # If the solution could not be found
     return None
```

Considering a set of N sets, the worst-case scenario is to loop for each element, and considering this is a recursive algorithm, we can expect a time complexity of n².

Hope this could bring light to finding a better solution.

Comment: Great! That seems correct to me! thank you for your time!